# Time Machine + FileVault on Lion or Mountain

Tags: macos, time-machine, filevault

If I stop the backup it says: "now encrypting...", is the data saved "not encrypted" before being encrypted? Can I make it "always encrypted"?

Non-encrypted transfers are a problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Machine on 10.7/10.8 uses the same encryption as any other non-system disk. When you first enable it, OS X has to encrypt the entire disk, which takes a while. The status "Encrypting" just means that it's still working on that.

You can check on the status with `diskutil cs list` in Terminal. Mixed in with other info, you'll see something like:

```
Size (Total):       124190560256 B (124.2 GB)
Size (Converted):   2539913216 B (2.5 GB)
```

That's 2.5 out of 124.2GB complete. Once the disk is fully encrypted, it's done for good and you'll basically never see that status again.